# Forwarding Network traffic from an interface to another in one PC

Tags: windows, networking, gateway, forwarding, crossover

I have two pc running on Windows. They are connected with direct Ethernet cable.
PC1 has two interfaces. One is connected to the LAN with static ip:172.16.50.2 mask: 255.255.0.0 and gateway: 172.16.20.1. and the second interface is used to connect directly to PC2 with ip: 192.168.0.1 mask:255.255.255.0 and no gateway. 
PC2 has one interface for direct connecting to PC1 with ip: 192.168.0.2 mask: 255.255.255.0 and gateway: 192.168.0.1 These two PC can see each other with no problem. But I want to access the LAN resources from PC2 without using Bridge on PC1. I have already enabled IP Packet Forwarding in PC1. What specific "route add" command should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PC1 already knows how to get to the LAN, and PC2 already knows how to get to PC1.  You can't add a route anywhere to improve on this situation and make PC1 route traffic from PC2 to the LAN.

What you need to do is enable Internet Connection Sharing on PC1's `172.16.50.2` interface. When prompted, select the `192.168.0.1` interface as the "home" network. This will configure PC1 so that it routes traffic between the two interfaces.

Comment: But I don't want PC2 to get ip from LAN dhcp.

Comment: Please see updated Answer